# CSS LIst Style Font Awesome not working

Tags: html, css, coding-style, styles

anyone can help ,
font awesome why I do not appear,
where the problem where,

[image]

Comment: where the problem where yes, so it will not show the font awesome

Comment: It's still unclear to me that what are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the external library, since FontAwesone is not a built-in font-family.

```
<link href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Something like this.